# Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to SOBJECT:Account

Tags: apex

I have created a custom field in custom object, in that i am getting the value and when clicked custom button "convert" which is create a new contact. But when converting i am getting this error.

Error Message:
**Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to SOBJECT:Account at line 37 column 9**

Code:

```
public class LeadConversion {
 public PageReference RedirecttoLead()
 {
    String currentLead = '/' + siteObj.Id;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(currentLead);
    return pageRef;
 }

 private Site__c siteObj;

 // The extension constructor initializes the private member
 // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
 // controller.
 public LeadConversion(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
 {
  System.debug('******sai******');
         siteObj = (Site__c)stdController.getRecord();
 }

 public void convertLead(){    
    Contact cc = new Contact();
    cc.LastName = siteObj.LastName__c;
    **cc.Account = siteObj.Name;**

   try 
   { 
    insert cc; 
   }
    Catch (Exception ex2)
    {

     ex2.getmessage();
    }     
 }    
}
```

Kindly anyone tell how to solve this issue.

Comment: I assume `cc.Account = siteObj.Name;` is causing the error?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot assign the standard field `Name` to the `Account` lookup. You will need an **Account-ID**. Something like this:

```
cc.AccountId = siteObj.Account__c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to set `siteObj.Name` as an `Account`, but you need to set the Contact `AccountId` field to a valid Account Id instead.

```
Contact cc = new Contact();
cc.AccountId = siteObj.[field for Account Id]
```

**Edit**

You can try out SOQL queries easily in [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com) and it has a query builder. You can also execute anonymous APEX through the [Developer Console](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_system_log.htm). Try running

```
select AccountId from Contact
```

in Workbench and you'll get a list of AccountId assigned to various contacts.

Comment: Hi mike, thanks for the reply.I am not having AccountId field in contact. Account Name field is lookup field in contact.I am this this error after i have made these changes.Invalid id: Voltum
Error is in expression '{!convertlead}' in component <apex:page> in page leadconversion

Comment: Try `Id accountId = [select AccountId from Contact where Id = {ID}][0].AccountId;
System.Debug(accountId);` in the Developer Console or Workbench. It's there.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I  am new to developer kindly tell where to use this.

Comment: Hi mike, I am getting these error after made thesee changes to apex class.Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '{' at line 38 column 65

Comment: {ID} was meant to designate a test id for demonstration purposes, not for your class. If siteObj.Name is a lookup(Account) then you would probably use `cc.AccountId = siteObj.Name.Id;`

Comment: Thanks mike, siteObj.Name is not a lookup field but Account Name in Contact Std Tab is a look up field.